# C# substring with multiple characters

Tags: c#, string

Please find the below sample possible strings

- `Orange+bhabha<<0`
- `Mango>foo>>10`
- `Apple Https://test.com<<5>>2`
- `Grape==50`
- `kiwi>>20<<5`

How do we extract text only from the above string list (e.g., Orange+bhabha,Mango>foo,Apple Https://test.com,Grape etc..)?

Please find the below sample my tried Codesnip:

```
    eg:var str="Orange<<0";
    str.Split("<<")[0].Split("==")[0].Split(">>")[0];
    // Output : Orange
```

It is working fine. Is there an optimal solution to solve this issue?

> ```
> Input -> Desired output 
> "Orange+bhabha<<0" -> "Orange+bhabha"
> "Mango>foo>>10" -> "Mango>foo"
> "Apple Https://test.com<<5>>2" -> "Apple Https://test.com"
> "Grape==50" -> "Grape"
> "kiwi>>20<<5" -> "Kiwi"
> ```

Comment: Why don't  you use regex to extract it?

Comment: What is "Codesnip"? *[code snippet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snippet_(programming))*? Or the name of a web site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Split` from string library:

```
string[] stringList = { "Orange+bhabha<<0", "Mango>foo>>10", "Apple Https://test.com<<5>>2", "Grape ==50", "kiwi>>20<<5" };
foreach (var str in stringList)
{
   var result = str.Split(new string [] { ">>", "<<", "==" },StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
   Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

One of advantages is that you can modify the separator easily.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a regular expression to replace all non-letters in the string with `string.Empty`

```
string result = Regex.Replace(<THE STRING>, @"[^A-Z]+", String.Empty);
```

However, the above will show *all* the letters in the string so if your string was something like 'kiwi<<02>>test' it would show 'kiwitest'.

After the latest revision, the following expression should work:

```
[^a-zA-Z:/.]+
```

Comment: Minor tweak:  [^a-zA-Z]  to allow lower case.

Comment: @Joe Yep. You're right

Comment: Sorry I have edited this post, Kindly please recheck

Comment: But this solution ignoring all characters eg Mango-foo changed to Mangofoo

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ That's because I answered the original question `How do we extract text only from above string list`

Comment: @PrasannaKumarJ Would the follow expression work? `[^a-zA-Z:/.]+`

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this

```
    foreach (var item in strList)
    {
        str = str.Replace(item, string.Empty);
    }
```